# Null Error Java Maze Solver

Tags: java, algorithm, nullpointerexception, maze

I have 2 objects. One called Cell and one called FinalSolve. The aim of the program is to solve a maze by looping through each cell looking for the exit.

The cell object represents the cell from the maze and has 4 instance variables 1 constructor and 4 other instance methods which return the specified instance variables.

```
    //the variables
    private int value;
    private int column;
    private int row;
    private char symbol;
    private int nuValue;




    //the methods
    public value()
    {
    return value
    }
```

And so on. My maze object contains 6 instance methods as follows:

- Solve
- Mark Path
- toString
- findNeighbors
- findCellWithValue
- setTheValue

They have a pretty straight forward name and they return exactly what I'm expecting of them.

### Solve

It's the method that using the algorithm and making use of all the methods specified above tries to solve the maze

```
public void solve()
{
    Cell[] entrance = findCellWithValue(250);
    Cell[] neighborsOf = findNeighbors(entrance[0]);
    for(Cell neighbor : neighborsOf)
    {
        setTheValue(1, neighbor);
    }
    int moveCount = 1;
    boolean foundExit = false;
            try{
    while(!foundExit && moveCount <= 200)
    {
        Cell[] theCells = findCellWithValue(moveCount);
        for(Cell justOne : theCells)
        {
            if(justOne.symbol() == '!')
            {
                foundExit = true;
                markPath();
                                    break;
            }
            else
            {
                Cell[] moreNeighbors = findNeighbors(justOne);
                for(Cell prostie : moreNeighbors)
                {
                    if(prostie.value() == 0)
                    {
                    setTheValue(moveCount+1, prostie);
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        moveCount++;
    }
            }catch(Exception e)
            {
            System.out.println("" + moveCount);
            System.out.println("" + e.getMessage());
            }


}
```

### Mark Path

This method is called once the solve method solves the program and it marks the path back from the exit to the entrance. Since I have encountered an error in my program this method is still in progress and it just prints "Hello"

```
public void markPath()
{
    System.out.println("Hello");
}
```

### findNeighbors

Looks in the maze for the neighbors ( which are the white spaces ) of the specified cell and returns them in an array.

```
    public Cell[] findNeighbors(Cell theCell)
    {
        Cell[] neighborsCell = new Cell[1];
        int neighbors = 0;
        int column = theCell.column();
        int row = theCell.row();
                    if(column - 1 < 0);
                    else
                    {
                        char some = maze[column-1][row].symbol();
                        if(some == ' ')
                        {
                            if(neighbors == neighborsCell.length)
                            {
                                Cell[] biggerArray = new Cell[neighborsCell.length + 1];
                                System.arraycopy(neighborsCell, 0, biggerArray, 0, neighbors - 1);
                                neighborsCell = biggerArray;

                            }
                            neighborsCell[neighbors] = maze[column-1][row];
                        }
                    }
                    if(column + 1 > 20 );
                    else
                    {
                        char someElse = maze[column+1][row].symbol();
                        if(someElse == ' ')
                        {
                            if(neighbors == neighborsCell.length)
                            {
                                Cell[] biggerArray = new Cell[neighborsCell.length + 1];
                                System.arraycopy(neighborsCell, 0, biggerArray, 0, neighbors - 1);
                                neighborsCell = biggerArray;

                            }
                            neighborsCell[neighbors] = maze[column+1][row];

                        }
                    }
                    if(row - 1 < 0);
                    else
                    {
                        char someElse = maze[column][row-1].symbol();
                        if(someElse == ' ')
                        {
                            if(neighbors == neighborsCell.length)
                            {
                                Cell[] biggerArray = new Cell[neighborsCell.length + 1];
                                System.arraycopy(neighborsCell, 0, biggerArray, 0, neighbors - 1);
                                neighborsCell = biggerArray;

                            }
                            neighborsCell[neighbors] = maze[column][row-1];

                        }

                    }
                    if(row + 1 > 10);
                    else
                    {
                        char someElse = maze[column][row+1].symbol();
                        if(someElse == ' ')
                        {
                            if(neighbors == neighborsCell.length)
                            {
                                Cell[] biggerArray = new Cell[neighborsCell.length + 1];
                                System.arraycopy(neighborsCell, 0, biggerArray, 0, neighbors - 1);
                                neighborsCell = biggerArray;

                            }
                            neighborsCell[neighbors] = maze[column][row+1];

                        }

                    }



        return neighborsCell;
    }
```

### toString

Overrides the default toString method and returns the maze as it is when read from the file

```
@Override
    public String toString()
    {
        String result = "";
        for(int row = 0; row < HEIGHT; row++)
        {
            for(int column = 0; column < WIDTH; column++) {
                            switch(maze[column][row].nuValue())
                            {
                            case HEDGE: result += HEDGE_REP; break;
                            case SPACE: result += SPACE_REP; break;
                            case ENTRANCE: result += ENTRANCE_REP; break;
                            case EXIT: result += EXIT_REP; break;

                            }
                        }//switch
                result += NLS;


        }//for
        return result;

    }//toString
```

### findCellWithValue

Loops the whole maze in search of the cells that have as value the specified int given as argument

```
    public Cell[] findCellWithValue(int theValue)
{
    int currentNoOfCells = 0;
    Cell[] theCells = new Cell[INITIAL_ARRAY_SIZE];
        for(int row = 0; row < HEIGHT; row++)
        {
            for(int column = 0; column < WIDTH; column++)
            {
                if(maze[column][row].value() == theValue)
                {
                    if(currentNoOfCells == theCells.length)
                    {
                        Cell[] biggerArray = new Cell[theCells.length + ARRAY_RESIZE_FACTOR];
                                            System.arraycopy(theCells, 0, biggerArray, 0, theCells.length);
                        theCells = biggerArray;

                    }
                    theCells[currentNoOfCells] = maze[column][row];
                    currentNoOfCells++;

                }

            }

        }
    return theCells;
}
```

### setTheValue

Sets the value of a cell to be the specified int given as an argument

```
public void setTheValue(int value, Cell someCell)
{
    int column = someCell.column();
    int row = someCell.row();
    char symbol = someCell.symbol();
    maze[column][row] = new Cell(column, row, symbol, value);
}
```

The try and catch statement in my solve method is for purely trying to figure out why and where the error occurs. And it prints out the moveCount to be 6 when I get the NullPointerException.

The maze from the file is a 10 by 20 rectangle surrounded by a hedges represented as "#". White space is represented as " " , exit as "!" and entrance by "?"

Also one might have noticed that my solve method starts out by finding the cell value of 250. This is the value of the entrance given in the constructor of the maze which looks like this:

### Constructor

```
        public FinalSolve(Scanner input)
    {

        for(int row = 0; row < HEIGHT; row++)
        {
            String mazeLine = input.nextLine();
            for(int column = 0; column < WIDTH; column++)
            {

                char character = mazeLine.charAt(column);
                switch(character)
                {
                case SPACE_REP:
                if(column == 7 && row == 7) 
                                    {
                maze[column][row] = new Cell(column, row, SPACE_REP, 20);
                                    }else{
                maze[column][row] = new Cell(column, row, SPACE_REP, 0);
                                    }

                break;


                case HEDGE_REP: maze[column][row] = new Cell(column, row, HEDGE_REP, 0);break;
                case ENTRANCE_REP: maze[column][row] = new Cell(column, row, ENTRANCE_REP, 250);break;
                case EXIT_REP: maze[column][row] = new Cell(column, row, EXIT_REP, 0);break;

                }//switch
            }//for
            }//for

        solve();            
        }//constructor
```

### The Error

Line 51 in method solve. This line:

```
 if(justOne.symbol() == '!')
```

Comment: When Java throws an exception, by default it prints a stack trace.  Very handy.  It will tell you the line of code at which it has a null pointer.  I'll wait for you to give us that, instead of looking through this code...

Comment: Way too much text and code to expect any volunteer to rummage through.

Comment: Line 51 in solve. if(justOne.symbol() == '!')   It's trying to access the symbol of a null object I might recall

Comment: Try to fit your question in one sentence - it will be more of use for you and easier for us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relevant code based on line you mentioned is causing the `NullPointerExpection`.

```
Cell[] theCells = (moveCount);
for(Cell justOne : theCells)
{
  if(justOne.symbol() == '!')
  ...
```

This means that `justOne` is `null` for some reason. `justOne` contains one of the values in the array `theCells`. `theCells` comes directory from `findCellWithValue()`. This array is initialized to have some default size and only assigned to when a match is found. If no match is found, every element in the array will contain `null`.

This means you need to do one of two things. 1) Check if a value in the array is `null` before processing it (and break the loop since you are adding values incrementally). 2) Not pass back null values.

Personally I think 2 is the better option as it does not put extra requirements on the user of the method. `findCellWithValue()` is written so that it grows the array as necessary. This is exactly what `ArrayList` was designed to do. If you use it, you won't get this kind of error and it will simplify your code. If you have a collection that will grow or is not guaranteed to always have the same size, it is usually a better idea to use a `List`.

Edit:
As others have pointed out, your question was quite large. I explained how I tracked down the issue to show how little was needed in order to find the bug. When you ask a question, try to include the minimal amount of code required to reproduce the issue. If there is an exception, always include the error message **AND** the stack trace. It should be clear that things like `markPath()` and `toString()` are not relevant to the question (unless they are mentioned in the stack trace, then only maybe).